# What property defines the margin of a paragraph or table?

Tags: c#, com, ms-word

I'm adding tables to a word document, and there seems to be an automatic margin that is applied to it.  I can move it to the left manually when the word document is open, but I want to be able to do this automatically using my C# code.

[image]

How can I do this using com and C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually find the best way to find the API method is to record a macro and look at the VB generated. Converting this to C# gives:

Selection.Tables(1).Rows.SetLeftIndent(5.4, RulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);

Comment: Excellent thanks!  And another tip for anyone reading this answer, you can have negative margins to push something past 0.